# Remote desktop clients : saved password lost

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remoteapp

We use remote desktop on a regular basis ( about 40 clients ).

On the client computers we save the passwords in *Remote desktop connection* ( by checking the checkbox 'save credentials'). Doing this the user name and the password gets saved in the registry.

On certain client machines, Remote desktop connection asks for the password after a few days. In the options of RDC, the checkbox 'allow the password to be saved' is unchecked, and we have to check it again to be able to save the password.

We did not find what triggers the loss of the passwords nor what could be the difference between the computers that loose the password and those that don't.

Notes :

1. We use RemoteApp. We usually connect using the shortcut created by installing the RemoteApp .msi package and not with RDC.
2. Most of the client computers are in remote locations and are in a Workgroup. We are SaaS provider for an application that runs on Remote Desktop

Comment: The only clue I have in that problem on my machine is that the failure to save passwords started right when I did an AD forced password change.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch This is happening on client that are mostly not part of  a AD domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did not the reason why those passwords stored in the registry get lost. And we did not find any solution neither to avoid the loss of the passwords

#### Workaround

We decided to use [Remote Desktop Plus](http://www.donkz.nl/), which is a wrapper around Remote Desktop Connection. It allows to store the user credentials (the password is encrypted) on the local machine.

With RDP+, it is possible to give the credentials on the command line. This example would launch the RemoteApp defined in RemoteApp.rdp with the command line option `-cmd`:

```
start rdp RemoteApp.rdp /o:"remoteapplicationcmdline:s:-cmd /v:host u=domain\user pe=hS4d8GmXlhV/fnfZ75L9WGQ==
```

The encripted password can be generated in an UI or on the commandline.